# Django admin - Foreign key popup '+' missing when overriding admin form field

Tags: django

I've set up a basic django site using the automatic admin, and was using the '+' button to add foreign keys (plants) while adding an Ingredient. However, the plants weren't ordered so I've had to override the form field as show below.

It seems though that doing this means the '+' button which opened the popup has gone missing - is there a simple way to reinclude this, or a better way I should be ordering the foreign key dropdown? Thanks.

```
class IngredientAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    plant = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Plant.objects.order_by('name'), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient


class IngredientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'description', 'plant')
    form = IngredientAdminForm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, have you set a [default ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) for your model? It might make more sense to set the ordering there than in the admin.

```
class Plant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name',]
```

If you want a different ordering in a form, then changing the queryset is ok. Note that out don't need to explicitly define the plant field in your form -- you can change the queryset in your `__init__` method.

```
class IngredientAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IngredientAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['plant'].queryset = Plant.objects.order_by('name')

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
```

In the Django admin, you don't actually have to define a custom model form. You can use the model admin method [`formfield_for_foreignkey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey).

```
class IngredientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    list_display = ('name', 'description', 'plant')

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "plant":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Plant.objects.order_by('name')
            return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
        return super(IngredientAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Is this possible for a ManyToMany field in a similar way as well?

Comment: You can't use  `formfield_for_foreignkey` for many to many fields, but you can override the `__init__` method as described.

Comment: With the above I'm getting `super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type` for the `super(IngredientAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` line. Just to be clear, I don't need to set form = IngredientAdminForm with the above?

Comment: You have a choice of two approaches. If you define a custom `IngredientAdminForm`, then you need to use `form = IngredientAdminForm` so that your model admin class knows about it. If you use `formfield_for_foreignkey`, then there's no need for the custom form.